# how to count specific links on web page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Related to  count links.

suppose i  open Google  search page. on that page nine language links available . i want to count only these nine  language links .

so how to count only language links?
 how to write xpath for  link or href in web driver.

Answer (score 0):

Check the html for these links and you should be able to get some common unique identification property.  Once you have that it is really simple.

list alllinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath or By.id ......)

you can then loop through them and perform any operation.

It is not displaying correctly as iam responding using my mobile but it should be a list of webelements.

Comment: i have tried this  List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a")); but this shows all links  and i  want count  only language links.  i have also tried (By.xpath( =id('addlang')) but this xpath is not working .

Comment: use this xpath -- //div[@id='als']//a

Answer (score 0):

First, get the element of div which contains the languages link. And find elements with anchor tag which has links like following:

```
div = driver.find_element(:id, 'als')
links = div.find_elements(:tag_name, 'a')
```

and then get count:

```
count = links.size
```

Above code is in Ruby. You can implement same logic with any language you want.